# How do I get the amplitude and frequency from a sound file?

Tags: python, audio, scipy

```py
y, sound = scipy.io.wavfile.read('mysound.wav')
```

If I plot the absolute value of ***sound***, is that the amplitude of 'mysound.wav'? That is, how loud the sound is?

What exactly is being stored in the sound? I know it's a representation of the sound? How does one get the frequency and amplitude from that representation?

Comment: Since `y` is the sample rate I would assume that the `sound` array is just a list of amplitudes.

Answer (score 0):

This is not too much a coding question but a physics related question! Your `sound` variable contains a list of "instantaneous amplitudes", but I think it is not what you are looking for. If your file is a pure sinusoid, then the maximum of your data will be the amplitude of your sound (its strength).

However, your sound might have amplitude variation over time. For example you can play strongly a note of an instrument and then it fades in slowly. The amplitude is thus defined in a short time period.

The sound can also be made up of different frequencies (harmonics, human voice...). A more complete description uses Fourier Transforms and [spectrograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrogram).